# Screen freezes when using Record Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I've been trying to use record espresso for a few hours now, but I just can't make it work on the project.
I've added:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

And I press run Record Espresso Test, and the screen just freezes at the first screen. It doesn't finish the activity, because it is a Splash screen. Even if I set another screen as a first activity it just freezes, it makes a request but doesn't show any results, or changes screen. I have animations turned off.

```
03/18 08:29:20: Launching TestRecorderapp
$ adb push C:\ProjectsGit\somelink\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.company.someapp.debug
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.company.someapp.debug"
Success
APK installed in 1 s 593 ms
$ adb shell pm clear com.company.someapp.debug
$ adb shell am start -n "com.company.someapp.debug/com.company.someapp.views.activities.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.company.someapp.debug | com.company.someapp.debug.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.company.someapp.debug | com.company.someapp.debug.test
Connecting to com.company.someapp.debug
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/tcar.someapp.debu: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.company.someapp.debug is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10222(com.company.someapp.debug) identical 5 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1385)
I/tcar.someapp.debu: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/Font: Change font:2
W/zze: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: com.company.someapp.debug, 1:820332358974:android:deb7661ca6fda492
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 14711
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.company.someapp.debug
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Persisting first open: 1552894248164
I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.7.30
V/FA: Updating deferred analytics collection: false
W/com.company.someapp.debug: type=1400 audit(0.0:5835047): avc: denied { read } for comm=45474C20496E6974 name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23336 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c222,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
V/FA: Checking service availability
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Service available
    Setting useService: true
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6a839d6
V/FA: onActivityCreated
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;->mConstructorArgs:[Ljava/lang/Object; (light greylist, reflection)
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
I/FloatingActionButton: Setting a custom background is not supported.
I/chatty: uid=10222(com.company.someapp.debug) identical 1 line
I/FloatingActionButton: Setting a custom background is not supported.
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://api.somelink.com/api/settings
    Accept-Language: en
    x-client-type: android
    x-api-version: 4.1.0
    --> END GET
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://api.somelink.com/
D/OkHttp: Accept-Language: en
    x-client-type: android
    x-api-version: 4.1.0
    --> END GET
W/MixpanelAPI.RsrcReader: Can't load names for Android view ids from 'com.company.someapp.debug.R$id', ids by name will not be available in the events editor.
W/MixpanelAPI.ConfigurationChecker: You can't have more than one service handling "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" intent filter. Android will only use the first one that is declared on your AndroidManifest.xml. If you have more than one push provider you need to crate your own FirebaseMessagingService class.
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized https://api.somelink.com(392ms)
    Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 07:30:46 GMT
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with,authorization, accept, accept-language,x-client-type,x-client-build,x-api-version
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Vary: Origin
    X-Request-ID: d7775f53-3ec9-4dae-ad96-0789e672ece9
    X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 29
    X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 0
    Via: kong/0.9.8
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
D/OkHttp: Unauthorized
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (12-byte body)
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ACCarSharingDrawerActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2030554288779527060}]
E/SensorManager: registerListenerImpl sensorName:lsm6ds3c Accelerometer Non-wakeup,isWakeUpSensor:false,callingApp: com.company.someapp.debug,callingPid:7032,callingUid:10222
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://LINK.TO.API (545ms)
    Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 07:30:46 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with,authorization, accept, accept-language,x-client-type,x-client-build,x-api-version
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    ETag: "4e4-7xR+HT/mxMa+pp02AdQTyyq5xFM"
    Vary: Origin
D/OkHttp: X-Request-ID: ae38af60-0eab-45a0-a63b-0a1ae4a8bc18
    X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 57
    X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 0
    Via: kong/0.9.8
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
D/OkHttp: {"Some response"}
    <-- END HTTP (1252-byte body)
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2325227289
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://link.to.api
D/OkHttp: Accept-Language: en
    x-client-type: android
    x-api-version: 4.1.0
    --> END GET
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
I/Choreographer: Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized https://api.somelink.com/api(143ms)
    Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 07:30:46 GMT
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with,authorization, accept, accept-language,x-client-type,x-client-build,x-api-version
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Vary: Origin
    X-Request-ID: c0112419-5fde-41b7-b940-c28a002e615a
    X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 77
    X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 0
    Via: kong/0.9.8
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
D/OkHttp: Unauthorized
    <-- END HTTP (12-byte body)
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://api.somelink.com/api
D/OkHttp: Accept-Language: en
    x-client-type: android
    x-api-version: 4.1.0
    --> END GET
I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://api.somelink.com/api/ (138ms)
    Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 07:30:47 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with,authorization, accept, accept-language,x-client-type,x-client-build,x-api-version
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    ETag: "2af9-wj9m57vexbsWcU5m7bfhEuhjvw4"
    Vary: Origin
    X-Request-ID: 668799cc-788b-43d4-96d7-eb8fd5614fc9
    X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 110
    X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 0
    Via: kong/0.9.8
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
D/OkHttp: {CORRECT RESPONSE JSON} <-- END HTTP (11001-byte body)
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Unsupported class loader
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Unsupported class loader
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 15090037
W/tcar.someapp.debu: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : f909f5a, Ida6448821d
    Build Date                       : 11/12/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.3.R1.08.00.00.423.039
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    Build Config                     : S P 6.0.3 AArch64
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:5835049): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23336 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c222,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:5835050): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23336 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c222,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.graphics.memory"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:5835052): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=3974 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c222,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:5835053): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23336 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c222,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
I/Adreno: PFP: 0x016ee170, ME: 0x00000000
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 1
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.changepixelformat"
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:5835055): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23336 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c222,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
I/Choreographer: Skipped 145 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.changepixelformat"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
D/: Successfully load libgui-plugin.so, this=0x76506f70c0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=2828ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=910300861918726, Vsync=910303278585296, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=910303285835193, AnimationStart=910303286168422, PerformTraversalsStart=910303290208266, DrawStart=910303309583109, SyncQueued=910303573194464, SyncStart=910303573524516, IssueDrawCommandsStart=910303574379828, SwapBuffers=910303689163213, FrameCompleted=910303691023943, DequeueBufferDuration=3761000, QueueBufferDuration=1051000, 
E/SensorManager: unregisterListenerImpl callingApp: com.company.someapp.debug,callingPid:7032,callingUid:10222
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3449
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
```

This are DEBUG Console logs. I tried it on another project and it was VERY VERY LAGGY. Am I missing something?

[image: This is what is says.]

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact problem. Tried disabling the system animations from developer options too. Can't figure what's wrong.

Comment: I figured out that it depends, on what device it is running. On some it works.

Comment: Which device did you get it working? I tried the emulator and a real One Plus 5 device. Sucks on both (T＿T)

Comment: Samsung S7. I had the same problem. On emulator didn't work on OnePlus didn't work, but on Samsung it worked with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on **Android Studio 4.1.1** using **Pixel 3 API 29**.
When the emulator is up, my application becomes stuck in blank screen (before the splashscreen)

Make sure that you had import Espresso dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

ps: https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/espresso-test-recording